# How to build a query in order to get not expired records in Yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have a model in my project which has several fields like id, name, due_year, due_quarter, etc. Here is my [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzh6q.png)

The issue is that I want to get that records where the field "due_year" is greater than 2017 and at the same time, the field "due_quarter" must be less than 4. In simple words, I am trying to get unexpired records. I tried to build a query like this:

```
$rows = Model::find()
    ->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'due_year', date('Y')])
    ->andFilterWhere(['<', 'due_quarter', 4])
    ->all();
```

but unfortunately i got expired rows as well.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It seems all right, have you tried to print the raw sql statement and run it in your DBMS?

Comment: here the info from debugger: SELECT * FROM `Object` WHERE (`status`=1) AND (`due_year` <= '2017') AND (`due_quarter` >= 4) ORDER BY `due_year` DESC. I do it in phpmyadmin, unfortunately does the same

Comment: You want the `due_year` greater than 2017 and `due_quarter` less than 4, but in the statement `due_year <= '2017'` and `due_quarter >= 4`.

Comment: what type of due_year field? is it varchar or int? it better to use int(4) instead of string so the query will be 
`where due_year <= 2017 and due_quarter > 4 and status = 1`